# Looking for Amazon DynamoDB java library

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for a java library that allows the the persistence and retrieval of Java POJOs.

Some specific features I'm looking for:

1. Annotation Mechanism for attributes describing how a POJO attribute should be stored.
2. Store, Update and Delete methods
3. Simple Finder mechanisms to facilitate the finding of data.
4. Utility methods for creating/deleting tables

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html) provided by Amazon.  It contains all the features that you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I have been using the AWS SDK. However I cannot the API very low level. For example I cannot define how to persist a POJO by annotating it's attributes.

Comment: The SDK has both lower level APIs and higher level APIs.  For the higher level portion, check out: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html
You can define a POJO and then add annotations to define what table to map it to, as well as annotations to define attributes and hash keys and range keys.  You can then use the DynamoDBMapper object to update/save/search using the POJOs you defined

Answer (score 0):

Check [jcabi-dynamo](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-dynamo/index.html), which is an object layer on top of DynamoDB SDK, for example:

```
Credentials credentials = new Credentials.Simple("AWS key", "AWS secret");
Region region = new Region.Simple(credentials);
Table table = region.table("foo");
Collection<Item> items = table.frame().where("id", Conditions.equalTo(123));
for (Item item : items) {
  System.out.println(item.get("name").getS());
}
```